# Is there a neater way to do this - php max()

Tags: php

Quick question hopefully, more curious of neatness than a problem here.

I am wanting to change a variable to another value only if the other value is, for example, larger than the original...

Eg.

```
if ($x < $y) $x = $y;
```

Or a neater way of doing this seems to be:

```
$x = max($x, $y);
```

My question is, is this (the latter) the best way. Or is there a neater way?
Thanks, S

Comment: `$x = max($x, $y);` is just fine.

Comment: What does neat mean? Is the objective speed or readability?

Comment: By neat I guess efficiency of code execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quicker and neatest method is:

```
$x = max($x, $y);
```

hope it answered your question

Comment: @Shun Mc if my answer actually answered your question then please mark it correct.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Saqib, Apologies been offline for a while. Thanks for your answer. All the best

Comment: @Shaun thanks for that, if you don't mind can you look at my last question and see if you can answer that it's also php related